# Efficiency in SQL queries

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

Say I have two tables, `employee` (with a character column `id` along with some other columns) and `orders`, with a column `employeeid` and `partno`, along with some other ids.

Is it more efficient to say

```
 select * 
 from employees, orders 
 where id = employeeid 
   and id = '22222'
```

or

```
 select * 
 from employees, orders 
 where id = '22222' 
   and employeeid = '22222'
```

or does it not really matter?

Comment: Oracle's Query Optimizer is sophisticated enough to take care of such matters.  So write in a way that seems clear for you and others.

Comment: You should start using explicit `JOIN` operator instead of the old, outdated and fragile implicit joins in the `where` clause.

Comment: Have a search for "Oracle transitive closure"

Comment: The best way to answer such questions for yourself is to run EXPLAIN PLAN for the two versions. In this case you will find that the execution is identical.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to do a join and in that case the second form isn't going to work as expected, it's going to produce an error. The first would look like this once qualified:

```
select * from employees, orders where orders.id = employees.id and employees.id = '22222'
```

The first equality is really specifying the condition to use when selecting rows from the `orders` table to join with a particular row from the `employees` table. The second is the one that's a conventional `where` selection criteria.

Answer (score 0):

The second check is unnecessary.  Oracle is smart enough to know that if A=B and B=C then A=C.  You don't need to tell it.

The best way to write that query is

```
SELECT     * 
FROM       employees e 
INNER JOIN orders o ON o.employeeid = e.id
WHERE      e.id = '22222'
```

Even if the best possible plan is to start by reading all the rows from `orders` where `employeeid` is '22222', Oracle will know to do it even though you didn't explicitly specify the condition

```
AND       o.employeeid = '22222'
```

Oracle infers the condition from the others that you did specify.